# angular servidor

Tags: php, angularjs, webservice, servidor

Hola estoy practicando con angular creando una web junto con PHP como Back en entornos (servidores) separados, PHP en Apache ofrece una API, y por ahora angular en mi PC que lee esa API (con `ng server`). hasta allí bien

Pero ahora quiero llevar angular(front) a un Servidor *digamos que sera el de producción*. Angular al realizar el build, genera unos ficheros js, donde van, si deseo tenerlo separado de PHP (la API).

¿En otro Apache, en un servidor NodeJS ... ?

Comment: creo que estas confundido, a tu proyecto angular debes hacer un ng build para que te genere unos htmls y unos js en una carpeta dist y esa es la que debes publicar con apache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les explico cual es el proceso para los que trabajan con Angular y quieran mostrar su compilación en Apache

**Ambiente de desarrollo:**
**1**. Frontend Angular: Al ejecutar `ng serve` se leventa un servidor http con puerto 4200 para ver nuestra app.
**2**. Tienes un servidor apache donde se encuentra tu backend usando php

En ese momento tienes dos servidores para un frontend y backend

**Ambiente de producción mostrar tu app frontend en apache**
**1**. Ejecutas `ng buil -prod` y se creara una carpeta **dist** en tu aplicación, que por dentro es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**2**. El siguiente es subir esos archivos a un servidor apache, te indico los pasos:

Implementación de la compilación de prod en Apache 2

Esto se puede lograr agregando un .htaccess (en el mismo directorio donde index.html) con los siguientes contenidos.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Este fragmento de código hace uso del mod_rewritemódulo de Apache, así que asegúrese de tenerlo habilitado. En Linux esto se puede hacer de la siguiente manera (probablemente todos los comandos se deben ejecutar como sudo):

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Reinicie el servicio apache después de eso

```
service apache2 restart
```

Además, para que el rewritemódulo funcione, la configuración de apache debería haberse `AllowOverride all` habilitado para el directorio donde se ubique la aplicación Angular. Esto se hace de la siguiente manera:

Abra el archivo de virtual Host, y agregue el siguiente codigo `AllowOverride All`

Este es un ejemplo de como debe quedar tu virtual host:
dominio: produccionAngular.me

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName produccionAngular.me
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp7.1\htdocs\appAngular"
                SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
                ErrorLog "logs/dash-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dash-access.log" common
    <Directory "C:\xampp7.1\htdocs\appAngular">
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Te paso una referencia: https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Deploying-prod-build-to-Apache-2

Comment: Para complementar lo que dice Jan Pierre Sanchez , lo de servidor NodeJs solo es necesario si quieres implementar un Server Service Rendering o SSR y seria necesitario un proxy inverso.

Comment: Hola, necesito ayuda en algo similar, ¿debo abrir otra consulta?, o ¿puedo preguntarte desde aquí?.